# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer while passing params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

i want to pass model name to prams[:required_model] but it's giving me conversion error
please let me know how this works

```
def method obj

required_model = obj.class.model_name.human
params[:required_model] = required_model

model_values_attributes = params[:required_model][:model_values_attributes]
    model_values_attributes.each do |key, value|
  if value[:value].blank?
    field_values_attributes.delete(key)
  else
    value[:company_id] = current_company.id
  end
end
end
```

when I do `params[:property][:model_values_attributes]` this works perfect so I want to pass model_name to whatever is in params[:ABC]

Comment: What's `obj`, and what's the stacktrace of the error, if any?

Comment: obj is like , `def controller_method obj` and the error is no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: i've updated code please have a look

Answer (score 0):

That error means you're trying to access an element X from an object that responds to `[]` using symbols instead of using integers;

```
"hej"[2]
# => "j"
[1, 2, 3][0]
# => 1
[1, 2, 3][:foo]
# in `<main>': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

So this line `params[:required_model][:model_values_attributes]` might be failing because `required_model` is a string (or an array) and not a hash. Or just because passing symbols to `[]` is not implemented.

Comment: how to can i give it like a hash

Comment: It depends. It doesn't seem to me that this `obj.class.model_name.human` should be a hash. Can you add more context to your question? What's the hash you're trying to assign to `params[:required_model]`?